Is "sore throat" used in a figurative sense rather than a literal sense?
In Bullet Train (2022), two individuals are arguing over their code names:

Lemon: And why am I Lemon?
Tangerine: Because you're sour. No one
likes lemons.
Lemon: That's bollocks, mate. Lemonades, lemon drops.
Tangerine: You got a sore throat?
Lemon: Lemon meringue pie.

Is "sore throat" used in a figurative sense rather than a literal sense?

No, it should more likely be considered literal but sarcastic, the guy is asking if the person trying to come up with lemon things that people likes wants lemon-flavored medication for a sore throat (even though he really has no reason to believe that is why the guy is making the suggestion).

He sounds British; I wonder if he is thinking of Lem-Sip, a widely used cold and flu medication that comes in sachets to be dissolved in warm water and drunk?

Wikipedia has an article on lemon drops which says they're eaten as sweets but were developed from a medicinal product. Tangerine is implying that nobody would want a lemon drop unless they had a sore throat, so evidently they're still associated with medicine to him. Lemon is certainly common in medicines as a flavoring for throat sweets, drinks, and similar products. I don't think you're supposed to apply too much logic to the conversation though.

@StuartF - My recipe for a cold remedy: in a mug, the juice of 1 squeezed lemon, 1 or 2 teaspoons of honey, half fill with hot water, top up with Scotch whisky (single malt might be a waste). Adjust proportions and amounts of water and whisky to your taste. Repeat as necessary.
